# Open source 3D render engine for Java

Tags: java, 3d

Which are the Open source 3D render engines for Java?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest [jMonkeyEngine](http://jmonkeyengine.org/), it is great.

Answer (score 4):

[jME (jMonkeyEngine)](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/) and [here](http://www.jmonkeyengine.com/movies_demos.php) are some game demos

Answer (score 2):

Just for rendering, how about [Sunflow](http://sunflow.sourceforge.net/index.php) ?

[image: julia quaternion render]
<sub>(source: [sourceforge.net](http://sunflow.sourceforge.net/gallery/v0070/small-julia.png))</sub>

Also, it should be possible to run other renderers that have commandline
interfaces, like [Yafaray](http://www.yafaray.org/) or [Pixie](https://www.renderpixie.com/) from Java.

Also, [Ogre3D](https://www.ogre3d.org/) is interesting for real time stuff.

Comment: Ogre3D is C++, not Java - but there is a Java wrapper: http://ogre4j.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [DevMaster 3D Engines Database](http://www.devmaster.net/engines/).

Comment: The list you provided is dead unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Ardor3D](http://ardor3d.com/), that's the kind of JME number 2, developped by the original authors of JME.